# Seaborn sns.set() changing plot background color

Tags: python, seaborn

In seaborn using `sns.set()` seems to be changing the background color of the
plot.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({"type":["A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"],
                   "value":[11, 14, 13, 16, 9, 8, 6, 10],
                  "date":["t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t4"]})

grid = sns.FacetGrid(df, size=12.5, hue="type", aspect=2)
grid.map(plt.plot, "date", "value")
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn1]

Then if I run `sns.set(font_scale=2)` (or just `sns.set()`), repeating the
same plot I get

```
grid = sns.FacetGrid(df, size=12.5, hue="type", aspect=2)
grid.map(plt.plot, "date", "value")
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn2]

This seems like somewhat odd behaviour to me. I would prefer the second plotting configuration but would like to obtain this without making an arbitrary call to `sns.set()`, unless of course this is the recommended approach.

Relevant version info

```
print("matplotlib version: %s" % matplotlib.__version__)
print("seaborn version: %s" % sns.__version__)

matplotlib version: 2.1.0
seaborn version: 0.8.0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, it seems that [`sns.set()`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set.html) was [called on import](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/aesthetics.html) in versions < 0.8.

The reason why calling `sns.set` without any arguments changes your plot, is that it has some default parameters. Looking at the documentation:

> seaborn.set(context='notebook', style='darkgrid', palette='deep',
>   font='sans-serif', font_scale=1, color_codes=False, rc=None)

So, using `sns.set(font_scale=2)` will change the fontscale, but will also change everything else to the default arguments of `sns.set`

Comment: So how to avoid this @DavidG

Answer (score 0):

Use white style to return default background:
sns.set(style='white')